# To provide vcap properties (of stored value for a key in credhub) to server.xml (liberty server)

Tags: websphere-liberty

I require to get and use the vcap properties `${vcap.services.credhub.credentials.key}` for DB password in my server.xml in a liberty application deployed in PCF.

I tried but the value is not coming as expected.

But for spring boot application the value is getting resolved from **credhub** (to store credentials) and resolved in manifest environment variable which is then used in server.xml.

Just like spring boot application how can we get vcap property value in server.xml?

I tried to read manually using cfenv library and assigned to some environment variable and that variable used in server.xml to pick. But where to place this logic? is ServletContextListener (contextInitialized method) a good fit? But that seems not working for me.

How can we set some environment variable *before* the server.xml is read initially in liberty server to set connection pool ready?

I tried setting value to a env variable from credhub via cfenv library. But server.xml is already taken and correct password is not taken already.

expecting the right place where we can set the environment variable before the server prepares the connection pool, getting configuration from server.xml

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/771081/java/provide-vcap-properties-stored-key#3533449

Comment: Everything defined in VCAP_SERVICES should be available to the app as environment variables.....both user and system variables. You can do `cf ssh <appname>` into the container to verify the variables.  Then in server.xml you can substitute with the value of an env var by doing `"${myenvvar}"`  (which you may already know).

Comment: Thanks Scott Kurz for the info.

It means in server.xml (liberty server config) I can specify like below? I will retry. 
Do I need to enable anything at server.xml additionally? 
**server.xml code fragment**
<properties.oracle URL="${env.ORACLE_DS_DB_URL}" **password="${vcap.services.Credhub.credentials.<keyname>}**" user="${env.ORACLE_DS_DB_USER}"/>
</dataSource> -->  
*****   vcap environment variable   **
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "credhub": [
   {
   ---------------------
    "instance_name": "Credhub",
  
    "tags": [
     "credhub"
    ],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ],

Comment: I tried this in server.xml for the bound application with the key name specified put under the credhub, but seems the value is not fetching. I tried in bootstrap.properties , server.env and manifest file tried separately, but could nt succeed. Is the format for the vcap expression is the same as we use in spring boot application.  password="${vcap.services.Credhub.credentials.<keyname>}"    where 'Credhub'  is the instance name Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Scott Kurz for the info. It means in server.xml (liberty server config) I can specify like below? I will retry. Do I need to enable anything at server.xml additionally? server.xml code fragment <properties.oracle URL="${env.ORACLE_DS_DB_URL}" password="${vcap.services.Credhub.credentials.}" user="${env.ORACLE_DS_DB_USER}"/>  --> ***** vcap environment variable ** "VCAP_SERVICES": { "credhub": [ { --------------------- "instance_name": "Credhub", "tags": [ "credhub" ], "volume_mounts": [] } ],

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).